# Delphi MySQL Field Validation

Tags: database, validation, delphi

The database table field may contain constraints that would prevent user from entering values. For example, an obvious error: if field is integer and user tries to enter "g" would trigger error. For subtle errors, like out of range, or number width =3 and precision=1, user may enter 100.1 and trigger error.

Using Delphi dataaware components, I can use DataSource-DataChange when a field has changed.

Is there a generic validate function that I could use to "test" the value for any errors? perhaps the function could provide a message result and string such as "number out of range..."

I believe I could write one, but I don't want to reinvent the wheel.

Thanks
Doug

Comment: TDataSource's events are not really the place for this.  TField has on OnValidate event - have you not looked at that in the OLH?

Comment: I am trying to make a generic handler for any field to see if it passes basic validation. I don't have access to each field's Onvalidate event on the form, but with DataSource-DataChange(sender: TObject; Field: TField), i can see where each field changes. Here is where i must either create my own validator or use something already available. The Database itself (MySQL, in this case) does the validation, but i'd like to get access before this happens.

Comment: Personally, I've always drawn a distinction between the user inputting a new record and updating an existing one.  So, I've always written a custom, multi-page input wizard for the user to enter the details of a new record, so the user is steered away from entering nonsense/invalid data.  This provides, ime, a far better way to do step-by-step validation against relevant business logic than a traditional data-editing form built of db-aware controls.  It's the only effective way I've come across do do anything like record-level validation.  A db-aware form is fine for data-editing though.

Comment: Btw, I assume you've considered using TDataSet's BeforePost event as a place to do centralised validation?

Comment: Thank you Martyn. I have the place where I want to do the validation. I just need to do the actual validation. Ideally, I just want to trap the EDatabase error at the application level that returns something like data out of range or something similar...

Comment: If you haven't already, you might want to take a look at the validators in the Jedi project library - see https://wiki.delphi-jedi.org/wiki/JVCL_Help:TJvValidators - this is the closest I've come across to what you seem to be looking for.